# How to point Log4net to its configuration file?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

We recently moved all our tests from NUnit to MsTest.  We are using Spring.NET for an IOC container and Log4Net.  Log4Net is unable to find the log4net.xml despite having it in test project.  Any ideas what it could be?

Here is the error that we are receiving:

> Unable to create instance of class
>   OurCompany.DataAccess.DocumentManagement.Tests.EmailVerificationTokensAdapterTests.DeleteTests.
>   Error: Common.Logging.ConfigurationException: Unable to create
>   instance of type Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter.
>   Possible explanation is lack of zero arg and single arg
>   NameValueCollection constructors --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   Common.Logging.ConfigurationException: log4net configuration file
>   'log4net.xml' does not exists. at
>   Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter..ctor(NameValueCollection
>   properties)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object[] args, ref SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeType
>   declaringType) at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeType
>   declaringType) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type,
>   BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo
>   culture, Object[] activationAttributes) at
>   Common.Logging.LogManager.BuildLoggerFactoryAdapter()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Common.Logging.LogManager.BuildLoggerFactoryAdapter() at
>   Common.Logging.LogManager.get_Adapter() at
>   Spring.Testing.Microsoft.AbstractSpringContextTests..ctor() at
>   Spring.Testing.Microsoft.AbstractTransactionalDbProviderSpringContextTests..ctor()
>   at
>   OurCompany.Tests.Common.Domain.SATransactionalIntegrationTestsBase..ctor()
>   in SATransactionalIntegrationTestsBase.cs: line 19 at
>   OurCompany.DataAccess.DocumentManagement.Tests.EmailVerificationTokensAdapterTests.DeleteTests..ctor()
>   in DeleteTests.cs: line 20

Here is what we have in the config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="common">
            <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <common>
        <logging>
            <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.TraceLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
                <arg key="level" value="All" />
                <arg key="showLogName" value="true" />
                <arg key="showDataTime" value="true" />
                <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
            </factoryAdapter>
        </logging>
    </common>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet of the `web.config` file, here's the steps: 
You can add a key in the `appSettings` that points to an external config file containing all the Log4net settings:

```xml
 <appSettings>
      <add key="log4net.Config" value="Configs\develop.config" />
  </appSettings>
```

Here's the external config file:

```xml
<log4net>
  <root>
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
  ...
</log4net>
```

While in your code you will setup the `XmlConfigurator`:

```cs
Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(New FileInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("log4net.Config")))
```